# Are Makefile variables environmental variables for that process?

Tags: linux, makefile, environment-variables

When I define a variable in the Makefile, what is it's relation to the environmental variable of the same name?

Example: I have an environmental variable `CXXFLAGS` exported by the process that has called `make` and in the Makefile there is a `CXXFLAGS = -pipe -g -Wall`. Does that overwrite my environmental variable? If I did `echo $(CXXFLAGS) which one will be printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in the GNU make manual section on [environment variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html).  And of course, you can trivially test it by doing exactly what you said in your question and seeing what happens.